# Match characters in oracle sql where condition

Tags: oracle

I want to match Col1 from Table a to colum1 from table B.

```
A       B
123     123-ab
234     234-bc
3443    3443-dd
```

However, value in table b has concatenated data. I want to match only the characters until before special character occurs(-). 
I tried this : `substr(table1.a,1,3) = substr(table2.b,1,3)`

But this doesn’t work as some values have 4 digits.

Comment: Take the characters to the left of the first occurrence of a - from B.  maybe... `table1.A = substr(table2.B,1,instr(table2.B,'-')-1)`

Answer (score 1):

use join and substr

```
 select * from table_a
 inner join  table_b on table_a.col_a = substr(table_b.col_b, 1, length(table_a.col_a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using REGEXP_SUBSTR() to match on one or more numbers from the beginning of the string up to but not including the first hyphen:

```
SQL> with a(col1) as (
     select '123'  from dual union
     select '234'  from dual union
     select '3443' from dual
   ),
   b(col1) as (
     select '123-ab'  from dual union
     select '234-bc'  from dual union
     select '3443-dd' from dual
   )
   select a.col1, b.col1
   from a, b
   where a.col1 = regexp_substr(b.col1, '^(\d+)-', 1, 1, NULL, 1);

COL1 COL1
---- -------
123  123-ab
234  234-bc
3443 3443-dd

SQL>
```